# Getting USB information in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, usb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG8Qt.png)

The code throws an error at the specified place, what could be the reason?

My goal is to write a code that shows that the USB is inserted when it is plugged in and disconnected when it is removed. I want to write this with the pyudev library.